# How can I setup twilio call record?

Tags: ios, twilio, phone-call, recording

I have an iOS app with Twilio calls and voice record.
I'm using Twilio Client iOS SDK.

When user want to call the connection is created with code:

```
 TCDevice* _device ...;
 TCConnection* _connection ...;

 NSDictionary* parameters = nil;
 parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
               phoneNumber,@"userId",
               @"false",@"record", 
               nil];
 _connection = [_device connect:parameters delegate:self];
```

When user want to record voice message I use this parameters:

```
 parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
               phoneNumber,@"userId",
               @"true",@"record", 
               nil];
```

Calls are always successful, but the record is often interrupted when the user speaks very softly or silence the first few seconds. In this case, the server returns a null Url of the record.

How can I cancel an interrupt call record if the silence?

Is it possible to remove the voice warning before the recording: "Please, leave a message after the beep"?

In which place it should be set: in an application, on home server or in the dev tools on Twilio?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Twilio docs on using recordings: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record

The default timeout is 5 seconds, which means if there is silence for 5 seconds (or perhaps someone speaking very softly) then the recording ends.  Perhaps increasing the timeout will resolve this for you?